# In Microsoft Access, How do I link textboxes on the main form to be the query parameters?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, parameters

I've done a lot of research on this subject and every answer I find deals with eliminating the parameters and using VBA to apply the filters. However, my query is the result of many subqueries and the parameters are created and used right from the beginning so I don't think that's a viable option. [This thread](http://www.opengatesw.net/forum/smf/index.php?topic=656.0) is very similar to my problem, the difference being that the person who asked the question can apply the filter to their dates at the end. I'm preferably looking for a way to literally sub my unbound textbox values on the main form as the parameters for the query since this seems like it would be much more straightforward than trying to find a workaround like I have been trying up to this point.

Quick description of my queries if it helps: My first subquery consists of dates, names, rates and dollar amounts. The user is asked for two parameters, a `[start date]` and an `[end date]`. The final query produces each distinct name, a matching rate and a sum of the dollar amounts for that name between the two dates. The matching rate used is the rate for that specific name where the date is the same as the `[end date]`. If the combination of the name and that `[end date]` doesn't exist, the rate used is 0. The intermediate subqueries consist of doing the calculations and finding which rate is used.

I'd appreciate any kind of help with this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the parameters in your query into references to the combo boxes in the frmMain, and add some code to requery the subform whenever the combo box changes, or whenever the user clicks on "Filter" button.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may wish to replace the [start date] and [end date] parameters with :

```
= Forms!MyForm!MyStartDate
```

And

```
= Forms!MyForm!MyEndDate
```

Where MyForm is an open form with two textboxes.

If you have a crosstab in there somewhere, you will also need to add a parameter line.

Comment: Thanks for the help, your solution also worked! I gave the check mark to iDevlop since he posted a little before you did. Sorry about that, but thanks again!

Comment: Indeed, but something quite different, according to the edits :)